# Getting a list object in a object with Spring and MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

This is my Employee class

```
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private float salary;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private Date joiningDate;
```

I would like to fetch the list of address of a particular employee from my mongoDB.
And I know to return a particular field

```
query.fields().include(addresses);
```

But it doesn't work for me. I got 500 Internal Server Error.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.example.demo.model.Employee using constructor public com.example.demo.model.Employee(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,float,java.util.List,java.util.Date) with arguments 60d5798c319336085ac8130a,hello,null,null,null,null] with root cause
```

This is my code

EmployeeReporsitory

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeRepository {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<Employee> findAddressesByFirstName(String firstName) {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("firstName").is(firstName));
        query.fields().include("addresses");
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Employee.class);
    }
}
```

EmployeeService

```
    public List<Employee> findAddressesByFirstName(String firstName) {
        return employeeRepository.findAddressesByFirstName(firstName);
    }
```

EmployeeController

```
    @GetMapping("/firstName/{firstName}")
    public List<Employee> getAddressesByFirstName(@PathVariable("firstName") String firstName){
        return employeeService.findAddressesByFirstName(firstName);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a stack-trace from the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is salary null in mongo?

salary of type float could not be null  it is a base type

you can modify it to Float or give it a value;

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the @Document annotation on your model and a @PersistenceConstrunctor with all the arguments?

Like in this example: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/com/baeldung/model/User.java

Comment: Yes, I do. Actaully, if I remove the line query.fields().include(addresses); I can get a list of employees. But I am not sure how to access fields in the object

Comment: And Address is a different document?

Comment: No. It is only another class defined in the scope